# Разработка аналога regedit в Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, gui

Нужно написать аналог утилиты regedit для работы с реестром Windows для курсовой на c++, можно и на c#. Хотелось бы уточнить, насколько вообще это задание сложное? Какие библиотеки можно использовать для этого? С помощью каких компонентов можно создать такой графический интерфейс (дерево каталогов и т.п.)?

[image: regedit]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83860/discussion-on-question-by-nick-name----regedit--windows-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это Windows программа в самой простейшей вариации. В главном окне - вертикальный сплиттер, в левой панели дерево (tree control), в правой панели список (list control). Графическое оформление легко исполняется даже на чистом WinAPI, с любым фреймворком вообще без труда. Пожалуй, проще всего будет Visual C++ и MFC - в шаблонах MFC проектов есть 'Explorer', который создает это приложение полностью, останется только добавить конкретное наполнение (то есть работу с реестром). Для работы с реестром можно использовать класс [CRegKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xka57xy4.aspx).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Выше произошел долгий спор на тему того, нужно ли асинхронно читать реестр для последующего отображения в treectrl и listctrl. Я считаю такую оптимизацию полной глупостью, и чтобы не быть голословным, решил написать небольшой тест, который читает основные ветки и сообщает затраченное время. Первоначальная версия с GetTickCount выдала все нули, так что пришлось переделывать ее на таймер высокого разрешения.

```
static double frequency;

void EnumReg(LPCTSTR szHiveName, HKEY hHive) {
    LARGE_INTEGER tm0;
    if (!::QueryPerformanceCounter(&tm0)) throw win_error();

    TCHAR szName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD uNameLen;
    DWORD nKeys = 0;
    LONG lr;

    for (;;) {
        uNameLen = MAX_PATH;
        lr = ::RegEnumKeyEx(hHive, nKeys++, szName, &uNameLen, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (lr == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) break;
        if (lr != ERROR_SUCCESS) throw win_error(lr);
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER elaps;
    if (!::QueryPerformanceCounter(&elaps)) throw win_error();
    elaps.QuadPart -= tm0.QuadPart;
    double elapsed = (double)elaps.QuadPart;
    elapsed *= 1.0e3;       // We need milliseconds
    elapsed /= frequency;

    _tprintf(_TEXT("%s:\t%u subkeys, elapsed time %7.3fms\n"), szHiveName, nKeys, elapsed);
}


void main() {
    try {
        LARGE_INTEGER freq;
        if (!::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq)) throw win_error();
        frequency = (double)freq.QuadPart;

        EnumReg(_TEXT("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"), HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
        EnumReg(_TEXT("HKEY_CURRENT_USER"), HKEY_CURRENT_USER);
        EnumReg(_TEXT("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"), HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT);
    }
    catch (generic_error &se) {
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(se.Message());
    }

    TCHAR pat[120];
    printf("\nPress any key...");
    _getts(pat);
}
```

В результате вышло следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда очевидно, что время наполнения и обновления контрола будет минимум на порядок превышать время чтения реестра. Это если говорить о уникально огромной ветке HKCR. Для любого другого ключа время чтения будет составлять микросекунды, так что любые многопоточные оптимизации тут будут неуместными.

Comment: Вы серьёзно рассматриваете возможность рисовать сложный UI на голом WinAPI?

Comment: @VladD А где тут "сложный UI"? Стоковые меню, tree view, list view и панель статуса. Собственно для целей обучения эти контролы даже можно было бы реализовать самостоятельно.

Comment: @VTT: В целях обучения — пожалуй. Но тогда уже стоит делать правильно, и поддерживать изменение размеров окна. Многие программы, написанные на примитивных фреймфорках, не содержащих layout manager'а, не поддерживают это.

Comment: @VladD, и вы считаете, что программы на WinAPI не поддерживают изменение размеров окна?  Да уж, заявления...

Comment: Я вот поглядел, regedit использует как раз стоковые контролы. А сплиттер - это проглядывающий кусок родительского окна.

Comment: @freim: Ну вы уж совсем меня за идиота держите. Поддерживают, если программисты реализовали layout management самостоятельно. Но слишком часто программисты не хотят заморачиваться, и на layout management забивают, т. к. делать это вручную неудобно. Я ж написал не «все программы», а «многие программы».

Comment: @VTT: А стоковый tree control умеет показывать иконки без owner draw?

Comment: @VladD, умеют стандартные контролы и иконки показывать, и WM_SIZE умеют сами обрабатывать, и многое другое они умеют. Вы бы хоть познакомились с предметом, что ли, прежде чем писать вот это все.

Comment: @freim: И правда, умеет :) Ну что ж, попробуйте перенести иконку в _конец_ надписи, легко? А WM_SIZE тут не при чём, откуда стандартный контрол знает, какой у вас layout окна?

Comment: Если автор ну совсем ничего не смыслит, то, по сути, не важно на чем он напишет - получится все равно мешанина лапши. Потому ответ сильно зависит от требований. Для wpf например надо заморочиться паттернами, а для винформс или mfc, насколько я понимаю задачу, можно просто контролов накидать да в событиях логику прописать и все дела